# my usb wifi dongle only turns on when pi is also connected via ethernet

Tags: networking, wifi, ssh, ethernet

(Using ubuntu 14 on a laptop)
I followed this [guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/167425/how-to-setup-wi-fi-on-your-raspberry-pi-via-the-command-line/) to set up my wifi by sshing into the pi via ethernet. I checked my routers networks settings and it showed two ip addresses from the pi, and I could ssh into the wireless address without a problem.

When I unlplugged the ethernet and restarted the pi the wifi address does not show up, and I can't ssh in.

I tried restarting it with and without ethernet with the same results. whats happening?

Here is my interfaces file:

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
auto wlan0

iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-ssid "Patty likes oldman"
wpa-psk "analrapist"
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

iface default inet dhcp
```

Here is my wpa_supplicant.conf file:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
ssid="Patty like oldman"
psk="analrapist"

# Protocol type can be: RSN (for WP2) and WPA (for WPA1)
proto=WPA

# Key management type can be: WPA-PSK or WPA-EAP (Pre-Shared or Enterprise)
key_mgmt=WPA-PSK

# Pairwise can be CCMP or TKIP (for WPA2 or WPA1)
pairwise=TKIP

#Authorization option should be OPEN for both WPA1/WPA2 (in less commonly used $
auth_alg=OPEN
}
```

Comment: Without knowing what you did noone can say. There are hundreds of guides on setting up IP on the Pi, most wrong.

Comment: added the guide used

Comment: what do you mean by turn on? power turns on or accessibility over network?

Comment: it flashes blue when it is working and accessible over the network, it only does this when ethernet is also plugged in

Answer (score 1):

> This applies to Raspbian Wheezy prior to 2015-05-05 for later (and Jessie) See [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

This SHOULD work, but without seeing your `/etc/network/interfaces` it is hard to know.

I do not think this is the best option.
I suggest `/etc/network/interfaces` should contain

```
allow-hotplug wlan0
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

iface default inet dhcp
```

wpa-roam will keep trying to reconnect when it finds no wired network.

wpa-conf option will not keep reconnecting.

It is difficult to find the documentation for these commands.

Comment: so I shouldn't put the password ssid and psk in the interfaces file? will it just get them from wpa_supplicant.conf?

Comment: There are many ways to do this. Anyone can read `/etc/network/interfaces` so this is a security risk. In addition you can put many different networks in wpa_supplicant.conf

Comment: this doesn't seem to be working, I've added the related files to my question

Comment: You didn't setup as above. I particular `iface wlan0 inet manual`. Frankly most people who try to set these up manually get it wrong. The easiest and most reliable way to set up initially is with a monitor attached to the Pi, using the GUI setup utility. After this you can use ssh.

Comment: It still doesnt work with this change. Unfortunately I don't have a monitor to use with it. I can use a remote desktop with ethernet though, where do I find the set up itility?